Why does Racket output 1 for (and 0 1)?
As the title asks, why does Racket output a 1 for a logical and between 0 1? The interesting this here is that the same operation but flipped positions of 0 and 1 give the proper output of 0. I'm no Racket/Scheme expert, but shouldn't a logical and of 0 1 return 0 or #f in Racket?
Welcome to Racket v8.12 [cs].
> (and 1 0)
0
> (and 0 1)
1
> 


Here it is from the terminal:


If no argument of and is #f, it returns its last argument.

Unlike many other languages, 0 is truthy in Scheme. #f is the only falsy value.
